# VBA to add username upon row creation

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a scenario that has several users entering data rows to an Excel table.  There is no shared workbook setup involved so only one user will have the document open at anyone time.  Is there a VBA method I can use to capture the name of the user that currently has the document open and insert it each time a line is added to the table?  Thereby giving an author for each row.

[image]

Comment: like `Environ$("Username")`???

Comment: The simplest way is to capture the Username (if on windows login). Use something like

`Sub Display_username()
MsgBox Environ("Username")
End Sub`

Comment: I will be using: `Environ$("UserName")` for the username, the main difficulty is the issue of inserting the value each time a new table row is created. Anyone have any ideas for this? Thanks, Dan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the following code in the code pane of the relevant worksheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Columns("A:N"), Target) Is Nothing Then Cells(Target.Row, "O").Value = Environ$("Username")
End Sub
```

of course you can fine-tune the `If` clause that have username inserted in column "O"

Comment: That's perfect thanks.  As this works for all new lines even outside of the table, could you suggest a sub that would nil the field if the rest of the data in the row was deleted?  Or for simplicity if the value in column G for that row was deleted?  Thanks, Dan

Comment: You are welcome. As per this forum rules 1)  since my answer fulfilled your question please accept it thank you 2) a new question requires a new post

Answer (score 0):

The following code will grab the name of the user:

```
Application.UserName
```

Answer (score 0):

I find on my work computer at least:

`Environ$("Username"‌​)` gives **Admin**
`Application.UserName` gives **IT**

Now, I could change my `Application.UserName` to my name - easy enough to do with a little knowledge, but I find a lot of office staff don't have that little knowledge....

Outlook on the other hand is often set to the specific user, so when Excel first opens and stored in a global variable:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim olApp As Object
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    MsgBox olApp.session.currentuser

End Sub
```